# How to solve these visualizations problems in this Java Swing login windows?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am absolutly new in Java Swing and I have a problem.

I have to create a login windows taking inspiration from something like this immage (something like this, scilicet the windows must show 2 text fields where the user insert its username and its password and a button to perform the login operation):

[image]

Ok, I think that this is pretty simple and I have realized the following class that do it:

```
package com.techub.crystalice.gui.login;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

import com.techub.crystalice.gui.Constants;
import com.techub.crystalice.gui.GUI;

public class LoginFrame extends SingleFrameApplication {

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> startup()");


        this.getMainFrame().setTitle("MyApp Login");
        //this.getMainFrame().setSize(600, 350);            // Setta le dimensioni del JFrame che rappresenta la finestra principale
        this.getMainFrame().pack();
        Container mainContainer = this.getMainFrame().getContentPane();     // Recupera l'oggetto Container del JFrame

        // Imposta un layput manager di tipo GridLayout per il contenitore principale: 3 righe ed una singola colonna:
        mainContainer.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));   

        // Contenitore rappresentato da 6 righe a singola colonna contenente i campi testuali e di input del login: 
        JPanel body = new JPanel();

        body.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));

        JPanel usernNameLabelPabel = new JPanel();
        usernNameLabelPabel.add(new JLabel("Username"));
        body.add(usernNameLabelPabel);


        JPanel userNameTextPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField userName = new JTextField();
        userNameTextPanel.add(userName);
        body.add(userNameTextPanel);


        JPanel passwordLabelPanel = new JPanel();
        passwordLabelPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"));
        body.add(passwordLabelPanel);


        JPanel passwordTextPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField password = new JTextField();
        passwordTextPanel.add(password);
        body.add(passwordTextPanel);


        this.getMainFrame().add(body);      // Aggiunge al JFrame principale il JPanel contenente il form di login


        show(this.getMainFrame());

        JPanel footer = new JPanel();
        footer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); 

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
        footer.add(loginButton);

        this.getMainFrame().add(footer);    // Aggiunge al JFrame principale il JPanel contenente il bottone di login

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame.class, args);
    }

}
```

This class use a litle framework named JDesktop that involves the definition of the startup() method but this is pure Swing code. The only thing to say is that I obtain the main *JFrame * by this code line:

```
this.getMainFrame()
```

This example seems to work bad, infact I have some aesthetics problems in the login form visualization because I obtain the following result:

[image]

As you can see it present many errors:

1. The JLabel and the JTextField are vertically compressed each to other
2. The elements ar centered and not aligned to the left on the previous example
3. The JTextField are to short

What can I try to solve these problems?

Comment: Try to use `GridBagLayout` as recomended in your another question

Comment: Initialize you JTextFields with a specified character width; `JTextField userName = new JTextField(20);`. or whatever number suits you.

Answer (score 3):

```
    JPanel passwordLabelPanel = new JPanel();
    passwordLabelPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"));
    body.add(passwordLabelPanel);
```

you have done similar code in several places, placing a component(`JLabel/JTextFeild`) inside another  container and then added it to the root container `body`. Any Panel has `FlowLayout` as its default layout which obeys preferred size of the component you are adding to it.  You are adding your `password label` to `passwordLabelPanel` but didn't set it's preferred size. The same issue you are having with the `TextField` and it's container `passwordTextPanel`. You can set preferred size to this `label` and `textFeild` to have some output which might satisfy you. But the truth is, You don't need this outer panel at all. Just add the label and text field directly to the `body` panel.

> What can I try to solve these problems?

The above explanation is also a solution. But in the long run they will not make any sense to you unless you learn the layout manager.

The Best, easiest, efficient way, worthy to have some effort is to start from here: [**Lesson: Laying Out Components Within a Container**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), Trust me, it will save you including us, lots of time.