# Some readability problems when a JLabel is on a background inmmage of a JPanel in Swing, how to solve?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

I am very new in Java **Swing** develompment and I have the following problem.

I have to create a JFrame window that have a background immage.

So I have perform the following operation to do it:

1) I have create a class named **JPanelWithBackground** that extends **JPanel**:

```
package com.test.login;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JPanelWithBackground extends JPanel {

    private Image backgroundImage;

    // Some code to initialize the background image.
    // Here, we use the constructor to load the image. This
    // can vary depending on the use case of the panel.
    public JPanelWithBackground(String fileName) throws IOException {
        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Draw the background image.
        // g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
        g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, 550, 230, this);
    }
}
```

As you can see this class read an immage file and put its reference into an Image object named **backgroundImage** and then draw  it on a **Graphics** object.

2) Then I have create a class named **LoginFrame2**:

```
package com.test.login;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;

public class LoginFrame2 extends SingleFrameApplication {

    private static final int FIXED_WIDTH = 550;
    private static final Dimension INITAL_SIZE = new Dimension(FIXED_WIDTH, 230);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("DENTRO: LoginFrame() ---> main()");
        launch(LoginFrame2.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Inside startup()");


        JFrame mainFrame = this.getMainFrame();         // main JFrame that represents the Windows
        mainFrame.setTitle("Chilli Login");

        mainFrame.setPreferredSize(INITAL_SIZE);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);

        Container mainContainer = mainFrame.getContentPane();       // main Container into the main JFrame


        // JPanel creation and settings of the MigLayout on it:
        // JPanel externalPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanelWithBackground externalPanel = null;

        try {
            externalPanel = new JPanelWithBackground("/home/andrea/Immagini/logo2.jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        externalPanel.setLayout(new net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout("fill"));

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"), "w 50%, wrap");

        JTextField userNameTextField = new JTextField(20);

        externalPanel.add(userNameTextField, "w 90%, wrap");

        externalPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"), "w 50%, wrap");
        JTextField pswdTextField = new JTextField(20);
        externalPanel.add(pswdTextField, "w 90%, wrap");

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");

        externalPanel.add(loginButton, "w 25%, wrap");

        mainContainer.add(externalPanel);
        //mainFrame.add(mainContainer);

        show(mainFrame);


    }

}
```

This class extends **SingleFrameApplication** abstract class of the **JDesktop** Swin framework that provide me a **JFrame** istance.

This class simply create the **JPanelWithBackground** object by the line:

```
externalPanel = new JPanelWithBackground("/home/andrea/Immagini/logo2.jpg");
```

and put in this object some Swing component.

This is my result:

[image]

My doubt/problem is: as you can see the **JLabel** that show the string **Password** is on the red part of the immage (of my chilli logo) and so is not very readable.

What can I do to make it more readable? For example can I set in some way that the background of my **JLabel** have to be white?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: No, may be another font or image.

Comment: `For example can I set in some way that the background of my JLabel have to be white?` - its easy to do but you don't seem so appreciate the help you get in all you other questions, so I'll pass on this one.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the background of the JLabel, but that would look ugly.  I would suggest just changing the foreground of only the Password label to be white. Possibly increase the size of font of both labels as well to help readability.

```
JLabel password = new JLabel("Password");
password.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
```

More extreme mods: would be to extend the label to output white text that is outlined by black, or to use images for the words in nice fonts that have transparency.

EDIT: 
Here is how to set the background to white.

```
password.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
password.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: please, can you say to me also how to set the background of the JLabel? Because the Windows version of our program (that is write in C#) use this way...and so it could be a good idea

Comment: Just added that to my answer, but this is really basic stuff, I would suggest reading some tutorials.

Comment: great and...last thing...can I set the opacity in percentage?

Comment: @AndreaNobili This question has been answered and you have yet to accept it. Do you not understand how the forum works since you haven't accepted answers from your other posting yet either!!! `can I set the opacity in percentage?` Why should people continue to help when you can't even do something simple like accept answers when you get help.

Comment: @AndreaNobili  *"can I set the opacity in percentage?"* Not easily. Generally speaking, Swing is either opaque or transparent. There are some "tricks" you can use, but they will only complicate your layout and application

Comment: @camickr, yes AndreaNobili haven't accepted one my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842836/how-to-solve-these-visualizations-problems-in-this-java-swing-login-windows) too. Well i am not hesitated about my answer being accepted, but at the very least a response, but no i haven't.

Comment: @AndreaNobili, please don't get us wrong. But the site works by responding upon we help each other. We are learning here, at the very least i am. When you respond to someone's answer, it makes clear that you are agreeing the user's post, otherwise you should make a point which intern would help us learning :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change the opacity of the back ground image...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();

    // Draw the background image.
    // g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, this);
    g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOvr.derive(0.5f));
    g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, 550, 230, this);
    g2d.dispose();
}
```